# CHrome extension in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, deployment

I developed an extension for chrome that interacts with my backend to answer questions. the extension is developed in Flutter?

What needs to be zipped and uploaded as package in chrome store?
Do i zip the complete directory with complete source code and everything or do i just zip the build web folder,that is created when upload when i test the extension in developer mode, and upload that as a package?

For now i am uploading build web folder but it keeps rejecting my extension, the only permission i am using is clipboardWrite and have justified that as "Paste responses from extension to browser".

Could not figure out the reason of rejection and till now there is no communication from chrome store support as i also raised a case with them.

Any help will do.
Thanks

Comment: You need to zip the build folder's contents in order to keep manifest.json at the top level of the zip. If you zipped the folder instead, then it becomes the top level and manifest.json is at the second level.